# multiple slide panels in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having multiple `jQuery` `sliding panel` in the same page, however when i show or hide one panel, the others become shown or hidden as well.
anyone can solve this problem?
Thanks.

```
code: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".flip").click(function(){
    $(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
</script>
<h3>Category: Health</h3>
<div class="panel" >
#{ifnot Posts}

    No posts to view

#{/ifnot}

<ul>
    #{list items:Posts, as: 'Post'}
    <li>

        <p>${Post.poster}</p><p>${Post.content}</p>

    </li>
    #{/list}
</ul>

    <a id="addpost" href="#">add new Health's post</a>

</div>
<p value="health" class="flip">Show/Hide Posts</p>
<h3>Category: Politics</h3>
<div class="panel">
#{ifnot Posts}

    No posts to view

#{/ifnot}
<ul>
    #{list items:Posts, as: 'Post'}
    <li>

        <p>${Post.poster}:</p><p>${Post.content}</p>

    </li>
    #{/list}
</ul>
<p>
    <a id="addpost" href="#">add new Politic's post</a>



</p>
</div>
<p id="health" class="flip">Show/Hide Posts</p>
<h3>Category: Entertainment</h3>
<div class="panel">
#{ifnot Posts}

    No posts to view

#{/ifnot}
<ul>
    #{list items:Posts, as: 'Post'}
    <li>

        <p>${Post.poster}</p><p>${Post.content}</p>

    </li>
    #{/list}
</ul>
<p>
    <a id="addpost" href="#">add new Entertainment's post</a>
</p>
</div>
<p id="entertainment" class="flip">Show/Hide Posts</p>
```

Comment: What does your selector look like that you're using to hide the element?

Comment: We'd have to see your code in order to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selectors apply a function to all elements that match it. For example a selector like

```
$(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
```

will match all elements that have the panel class.

A simple solution would be to use ids to identify the panel you want to operate on.

```
<div id="panel1" class="panel"> .. </div>
<div id="panel2" class="panel"> .. </div>
<div id="panel3" class="panel"> .. </div>
```

And then in the jquery selector address this panel explicitly using

```
$("#panel1").slideToggle("slow");
```